# Create numpy matrix from output of function on vector vs vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two vectors / one-dimensional `numpy` arrays and a function I want to apply:

```py
arr1 = np.arange(1, 5)
arr2 = np.arange(2, 6)
func = lambda x, y: x * y
```

I now want to construct a `n * m` matrix (with `n`, `m` being the lengths of `arr1`, and `arr2` respectively) containing the values of the function outputs. The naive approach using for loops would look like this:

```py
np.array([[func(x, y) for x in arr1] for y in arr2])
```

I was wondering if there is a smarter vectorized approach using the `arr1[:, None]` syntax to apply my function - please note my actual function is significantly more complicated and can't be broken down to simple `numpy` operations (`arr1[:, None] * arr2[None, :]` won't work).

Comment: I think that is pretty neat and if your function is really complicated there is not much you can do

Comment: Perhaps there is some numpy approach but if your function is really complex, and lets suppose very slow, perhaps is worth optimizing the function first

Comment: Each function call is ~20ms and my array could get up to a few thousand entries large so it would take a few hours / days to compute

Comment: @BBQuercus, If you add real complicated function we can optimize your real function with [tag:numba]

Comment: @BBQuercus, Where is your function take too much? is because of `biopython`?

Comment: @BBQuercus, The second part of your question is not related to the first part, It's better to break these two-part into two questions. It's better for each question asks about one subject.

Comment: @l'mahdi I haven't profiled it properly but the longest part is the actual `biopython` alignment step. I'll remove the actual function again and was hoping there was just some slightly cleaner way to spread out a function like with @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `numpy.array`, One approach can be [`numpy.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). Because you want to compute this : `arr1_i * arr2_j -> insert to arr_result_ji`.

```
>>> np.einsum('i, j -> ji', arr1, arr2)
array([[ 2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16],
       [ 5, 10, 15, 20]])
```

Or you can use [`numpy.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) or use `@`.

```
>>> np.matmul(arr2[:,None], arr1[None,:])
# OR
>>> arr2[:,None] @ arr1[None,:]
# Or by thanks @hpaulj by elementwise multiplication with broadcasting
>>> arr2[:,None] * arr1[None,:]
array([[ 2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16],
       [ 5, 10, 15, 20]])
```

Comment: `arr2[:,None] * arr1[None,:]` also works - elementwise multiplication with `broadcasting`

Answer (score 1):

Here is some comparison between your loop approach and @I'mahdi 's approach:

```py
import time
arr1 = np.arange(1, 10000)
arr2 = np.arange(2, 10001)


start = time.time()
np.array([[func(x, y) for x in arr1] for y in arr2])
print('loop: __time__', time.time()-start)

start = time.time()
(arr1[:, None]*arr2[None, :]).T
print('* __time__', time.time()-start)

start = time.time()
np.einsum('i, j -> ji', arr1, arr2)
print('einsum __time__', time.time()-start)

start = time.time()
np.matmul(arr2[:,None], arr1[None,:])
print('matmul __time__', time.time()-start)
```

Output:

```
loop: __time__ 70.3061535358429
* __time__ 0.43536829948425293
einsum __time__ 0.508014440536499
matmul __time__ 0.7149899005889893
```